# Directions for creating a new project from scratch using TFS source control/VS2012

Tags: tfs

I can't seem to find any simple docs for helping me start a new project and use TFS 2012 source control. We are a small shop with only 2 people doing any coding and I have the following objectives:

1. I want to create branches as we work on new features
2. Would be great if I could publish the main branch to azure web site automatically
3. I'm starting from scratch, no project created in VS2012 or in TFS
4. Don't want all the nuget packages checked into TFS
5. How should I name the directories, the solution, the projects and the tfs project?
6. What is the order of the steps I should take to do all of this?

Any examples would be fantastic.

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions here, and that's not the best fit for a Stack Overflow Question. My best advice is to lookup all the ALM Rangers guidance on Codeplex. The Branching and Merging one should cover all but #2 and #5. #2 Have a look at [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs) and #5, is what ever your team thinks is best.

Comment: Sorry about the rambling, just getting frustrated. I've read the ALM Rangers guidance on branching/merging but it didn't give me enough details about setting up the actual file directory structure. I got #2 working fine. As for what the team thinks is best... I AM the team :) Looking for examples basically. Appreciate the reply, thanks.